# Update resource AJAX Laravel 5

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, laravel

I'm getting stuck with Ajax, i dont know why my ajax call returns error everytime.
My update method dont even detect an ajax request. I've never done ajax before, but i understand the logic behind it so excuse my ignorance if i ask for dumb things lol..

```
  Route::post('edit/organisation/{id}',['uses' => 'OrganisationsController@update', 'as' => 'admin.organisation.update']);
```

Here is my controller method :

```
 public function update($route = null, $id, \Illuminate\Http\Request $request)
    {
        $org = Organisation::find($id)->first();
        if($request->ajax())
        {
            dd('OK ITS AJAX');

        }
        if($org->update($request->all()))
        {
            //return redirect('admin/dashboard');
            return redirect()->back();
        }
    }
```

And here is my ajax

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
var form = $('.update_ajax');
form.bind('submit',function()
{

    $.ajax({
       type: form.attr('method'),
        url: form.attr('action'),
        data: form.serialize(),
        success: function(data)
        {
            alert(data);
        },
        error: function(data)
        {
            console.log('error');
        }
    });

});
});
```

And here is my HTML

```
  {!! Form::model($org,['route' => ['admin.organisation.update',Route::input('name'), $org->id],'class' => 'update_ajax' ]) !!}


            {!! Form::label('name','Nom') !!}
            {!! Form::text('org_name',null,['class'=> 'form-control'])!!}
            {!! Form::label('org_type','Type') !!}
            {!! Form::text('org_type',null,['class'=> 'form-control'])!!}
            {!! Form::label('siren','Numéro de SIREN') !!}
            {!! Form::text('org_siren',null,['class'=> 'form-control']) !!}

            {!! Form::label('org_ape_naf','Numéro APE NAF') !!}
            {!! Form::text('org_ape_naf',null,['class'=> 'form-control']) !!}
            {!! Form::submit('Appliquer',['class' => 'submit-data-btn']) !!}


            {!! Form::close() !!}
```

Comment: What error does it return ?

Comment: sorry it doesnt return an error actually, it justs goes straight to my error scope.. so when i said error i was talking about the console.log('error') in my ajax method

Comment: `dd('OK ITS AJAX');` stands for dump & die. Die is forcing your app to exit, and that is seen as an error by jquery. Try `return 'this is ajax';` on that line.

Comment: I tried what you've said but like i said my method doesnt detect an ajax request so it justs update my database in the usual way

Comment: Try `echo 'ajax';` you can't `return` data to ajax request, it has to be either `text/html` or in `json` format

Comment: @lameduz show your html, is your form method POST?

Comment: instead of echo or dd use   return response('some text' , 200) ;

Comment: @vitr yes my method is post, i added HTML.

Comment: GUYS i told you i can echo whatever you want but the method $request->ajax() just returns false so its ignored, sorry if my english is bad but its what i'm trying to say haha

Comment: Route::post('edit/organisation/{id}'.. vs
'route' => ['admin.organisation.update'
what do you think?

Comment: well 'admin.organisation.update' is an alias for Route::post('edit/organisation/{id}

Comment: @lameduz  can you post an actual html result, not the blade template, just to ensure the route

Comment: Is your page refreshing when you submit?  I don't see how you are preventing it from submitting so the AJAX can work.

Comment: `<form method="POST" action="http://test.intranet.dev/admin/edit/organisation/3" accept-charset="UTF-8" class="update_ajax"><input name="_token" type="hidden" value="j4u4RGlqzaGEE3HIpobm70jME8poikb4Cn5sUbJ7">`

Comment: @lameduz  should this be Route::post('admin/edit/organisation/{id}'
just looking at the route...

Comment: this route is in a route group for prefix "admin" so i dont have to write it

Comment: @user3158900 y my page is refreshing ..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You aren't preventing default from happening when you click the submit button which is preventing the AJAX from completing and forcing it into the error method each time.  It also explains why in your PHP, the `$request->ajax()` is returning false.

```
form.bind('submit',function(e)
{
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        type: form.attr('method'),
        url: form.attr('action'),
        data: form.serialize(),
        success: function(data) {
            console.log(data);
        },
        error: function(data) {
            console.log('error');
        }
    });
});
```